# How to find all function calls a defined function makes? (including recursive and futher down the stack calls)

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using Python's AST module, and stuck on a given problem (it may be that AST isn't the right tool for this problem).

I want to determine if a given function (let's say "print" as an example) is called, by a defined function.

For example:

file_one.py

```py
def some_function():
    print("hello!")
```

file_two.py

```py
from file_one import some_function

def one():
    print("hi!")

def two():
    one()

def three():
    some_function()

def four():
    three()
```

How can I parse `file_two.py` and figure out which functions (in this case all of them) call `print`?

At the moment, I have something like this:

```py
import ast

class Visitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node: ast.AST):
        for child in ast.walk(node):
            if isisntance(child, ast.Call) and child.func.id == "print":
                print(f"Found a function that calls print!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("file_two.py") as file:
        tree = ast.parse(file.read())
    Visitor().visit(tree)
```

But this only works for the function `file_two.one` and no others.

Comment: This is less a question of syntax, and more one of semantics. It's not enough to check if `child.func` *is* `print`, but whether it is a function itself that calls `print`. This involves recursive "evaluation" of `child.func`.

Comment: And this ignores things like branching, which might prevent a call to `print` that exists *statically* from actually being *reached*.

Comment: Yes, that's true @chepner - definitely a problem with the "current code" I put up there. I played around with making it recursive, which solved the problem of picking up `one` and `two` - but I don't know how to "jump into a definition" for an imported function using AST (or any other tool)

Comment: Precisely: *syntactically*, you know nothing about `some_function` other than it is a name imported from `file_one`. The `ImportFrom` nodes doesn't contain any information about what that means, only that `file_one` and `some_function` are related somehow.

Comment: The code generator is what knows how to turn the `ImportFrom` node into code involving the built-in `__import__` function, which is a black box that turns the name `some_function` into a binding to some `function` object at runtime.

Comment: Ahh, that's really interesting - I hadn't really fully understood how the AST was working, but that makes sense that's it's just understanding the syntax in a file and not the semantics. Which I guess means that AST wouldn't be capable of realising where an import should come from, loading and then parsing it.

I'd be interested in whether anything in the python toolchain is capable of this kind of parsing? (obviously type anaylsis is, but that is using function hinting etc, rather than actually loading any function body contents)

Comment: Well, `python` :) But what you want is related to dead-code elimination (except instead of knowing whether a block of code is reachable or not, you want to know if a particular function call exists in a reachable block). It's beyond parsing, and touches at least on the surface the question of execution.

Comment: I've seen 3rd-party projects that do this kind of analysis, but nothing I'm aware of that ships with the interpreter.